# ECDsa Class in System.Security.Cryptography - How to supply K

Tags: c#, cryptography, ecdsa

I am trying to use the ECDsa Class in System.Security.Cryptography, but need to generate deterministic signatures.

Some libraries like bouncycastle implement something that looks like this

```
ECDsaSigner signer = new ECDsaSigner(new HMacDsaKCalculator(new Sha256Digest()));
```

Where the ECDsaSigner takes an object which allows you to control K to some degree.

Is there some way to use the ECDsa Class in System.Security.Cryptography and control K ?

Comment: As far as I know deterministic ECDSA (see RFC 6979) is not supported in .NET out of the box, i.e. for this you need a third party library, e.g. BouncyCastle.

Comment: agreed, not exposed, if it were you should use the hash of the message or equiv. Anyway, try EdDSA its usually deterministic.

Comment: Thanks you both, it does seem that you're correct.